# mingw to cygwin

Tags: c, cygwin, mingw

I am a newbie in cygwin.  However, I have used mingw so far, but it is not supporting fork(), so I need to switch to cygwin.  I have created a build.bat file in my mingw (programming language C):

```
gcc -o mask mask.c -pg -I/c/opencv/build/include  -lopencv_core231 -lopencv_highgui231 -lopencv_imgproc231 -L. -L/c/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can run this .bat file at cygwin or refer me to a site.

How can I run mingw executable with cygwin? Any refernce will be appreciated.

Thanks for your help

Emon

Comment: What have you tried in Cygwin that hasn't worked? Looks pretty straight forward for gcc.

Comment: You should seriously consider using Makefiles and make for the build jobs. that way you can be native to cygwin environment. Mixing cygwin/DOS does not sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that cygwin can run `cmd` (DOS command interpreter), which can then run your batch file. The problem is that `cmd` won't be able to use the non-windows paths that you have in your batch script. Try to run: `cmd /c myBuildFile.bat` at a cygwin prompt, and you should see what I mean.

It is better to use cygwin-style tools for making a build script. You should have the [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) program on your path which will allow you to write simple and more complex build scripts.

Alternatively you could convert your `.bat` build script into a shell script, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc -o mask mask.c -pg -I/c/opencv/build/include  -lopencv_core231 -lopencv_highgui231 -lopencv_imgproc231 -L. -L/c/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib
```

Name it anything, e.g. myBuildScript.sh, then make it executable with: `chmod u+x myBuildScript.sh`.

Comment: +1 When using Cygwin, it's better to use it completely than to try and mix DOS functionality and Linux functionality.